Having trouble adding an Image React Bootstrap
I am trying to show an image with a description to illustrate I project I worked on. I imported the img from the project file and tried to use it in the projects component. Nothing is showing up
enter image description here
This above image was the result of the below code.
Component:
import { Row, Col, Container, TabContainer, TabContent, TabPane, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';
import ProjectCard from '../components/ProjectCard';
import img1 from '../assets/images/img-1.jpg';
import '../pages/Projects.css';

export default function Projects() {
  const projects = [
    {
      title: 'YelpCamp',
      description: 'blog application for campgrounds around the world',
      imgUrl: img1,
    },
  ];

  return (
        <section className='project' id='projects'>
          <Container>
            <Row className='align-items-center'>
              <Col xl={6}>
                    <TabContainer id='projects-tab' defaultActiveKey='first'>
                      <Nav variant='pills' className='nav-pills mb-5' id='pills-tab'>
                        <Nav.Item>
                          <Nav.Link eventKey="first">YelpCamp</Nav.Link>
                        </Nav.Item>
                      </Nav>
                      <TabContent>
                        <TabPane eventKey='first'>
                          <Row>
                            {
                              projects.map((project, index) => {
                                return (
                                  <ProjectCard 
                                    key={index}
                                    {...project}
                                  />
                                )
                              })
                            }
                          </Row>
                        </TabPane>
                      </TabContent>
                    </TabContainer>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </section>
  );
};

CSS:

.project {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 50%;
}

.project .nav.nav-pills {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.project .nav.nav-pills .nav-item {
    width: 33.33333%;
}

.project .nav.nav-pills .nav-link {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 17px 0;
    color: #151515;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 17px;
    letter-spacing: 0.8px;
    font-weight: 500;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 0;
}

.project .nav.nav-pills .nav-link.active::before {
    width: 100% !important;
}

.project .nav.nav-pills .nav-link.active {
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.nav-link#projects-tabs-tab-first {
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 55px 0px 0px 55px;
}

.proj-imgbx {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.proj-imgbx::before {
  content: "";
  background: linear-gradient(90.21deg, #AA367C -5.91%, #4A2FBD 111.58%);
  opacity: 0.85;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.proj-imgbx:hover::before {
  height: 100%;
}
.proj-txtx {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 65%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.proj-imgbx:hover .proj-txtx {
  top: 50%;
  opacity: 1;
}
.proj-txtx h4 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
  line-height: 1.1em;
}
.proj-txtx span {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
}
.background-image-right {
  top: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 35%;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -4;
}

I expected to see the image and the project's description so that I can place them side by side on the right hand side of the page.

Can you also share the code structure of the ProjectCard component? Looks like the issue related to it

I figured it out! But I'll post that code here just in case!
import { Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
export default function ProjectCard ({ title, description, imgUrl }) {
return (




{title}
{description}



)
}
